# iTextSharp - html text into cell

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I need to create a Quotation PDF.
I want to write an text with HTML codes into a table cell.

```
...
 Dim texto As String
 texto = Server.HtmlDecode("descripcion del producto<br />DESC")
 table.AddCell(AgregaCelda(doc, texto))
 doc.Add(table)
...
Private Shared Function AgregaCelda(ByVal doc As iTextSharp.text.Document, ByVal Texto As   String) As iTextSharp.text.Cell
    Dim cell As iTextSharp.text.Cell = New iTextSharp.text.Cell(Texto)
    cell.Border = 0.0F
    Return cell
End Function
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Is the HTML appearing as text and not being rendered?

Comment: Yes Chris, it is showing something like <br /> ...some text...<ul><li>... something like this, and I need to be rendered as an HTML.

Comment: PDF and HTML are 100% unrelated. However, iTextSharp has a helper library called XmlWorker that will, to a point, translate some HTML tags into PDF commands.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was trying this the HTMLWORKER and PARSE the text into the PDF, but I don´t know how to control it to appears in a table cell. Sorry my engligh is not very good.                   Dim hw As New iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(doc)
            hw.Parse(New StringReader(texto))

Comment: HTMLWorker is old and not maintained anymore. It supports very simple HTML, basically bold, italic and simple font information. XmlWorker is where all current work is being done. If you search this site you'll find many examples of both. If you have only simple things like `<br />` you can (and should) just use iTextSharp. Otherwise, try one of the parsers and let us know what problems you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
        table.AddCell("Some rich text:");
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

        string htmlText =
            "<a class=\"unknownlink\" href=\".ashx\" title=\"\"></a><div class=\"imageleft\"></div><br><br><br><div style=\"font-size: 16px;\"><b>PDFsharp</b></div><b>A .NET library for processing PDF</b><br><br><br><b>PDFsharp</b> is the Open Source .NET library that easily creates and processes PDF documents on the fly from any .NET language. The same drawing routines can be used to create PDF documents, draw on the screen, or send output to any printer.<br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"pagelink\" href=\"Overview.ashx\" title=\"Overview\">Overview</a><br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"pagelink\" href=\"Features.ashx\" title=\"Features\">Features</a><br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"pagelink\" href=\"Downloads.ashx\" title=\"Downloads\">Downloads</a><br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"internallink\" href=\"/wiki/PDFsharpFirstSteps.ashx\" title=\"First Steps\">First Steps</a>  <small>'</small><br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"internallink\" href=\"/wiki/PDFsharpArticles.ashx\" title=\"Articles\">Articles</a>  <small>'</small><br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"internallink\" href=\"/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx\" title=\"Samples\">Samples</a> <small>'</small><br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"internallink\" href=\"/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx\" title=\"FAQs\">FAQs</a>  <small>'</small><br>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<a class=\"internallink\" href=\"/wiki/\" title=\"Wiki\">Wiki</a>  <small>'</small><br>";
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlText))
        {
            List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null);
            foreach (IElement e in elements)
            {
                //Add those elements to the paragraph
                cell.AddElement(e);
            }
        }

        table.AddCell(cell);
```